# Github api Publish a draft release

Tags: github, github-api, github-actions

I have draft release automatically created with github actions.
We can access its url or any other variable.

How can I publish it using github api is there any endpoint or something?

Comment: I don't think this answers your question, but it's related — here's a link to a Python script I have that uses the GitHub API to publish a non-draft release. It might be helpful. https://github.com/Samasaur1/DiceKit/blob/ce0d45142b0d7ea8089c6f6a2db10d5292f1e4ec/scripts/release.py#L32-L50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer for how to do it using curl but

This github action can do it for you-
[Publish Release](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-release)